# How to run sharepoint management shell in task scheduler

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell

When configuring task scheduler to run the SharePoint management shell it opens  as windows powershell not in SharePoint management shell.

The script I made is running well under SharePoint management shell but not in windows powershell.

When opening the target file location of SharePoint management shell it points the same .exe as windows powershell. how is that possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the PSSnapin for Microsoft SharePoint Server. Just add the following line to the beginning of your script.

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Without this Snapin, the powershell does not know commands like Get-SPxxx.

Comment: what? i was searching a lot and now i found it. thanks for the help. you my nigga.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Management Shell in start menu is actually a shortcut to regular powershell with some predefined startup script.

If you open properties for this shortcut you will find something like this:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell.exe  -NoExit  " & ' C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\CONFIG\POWERSHELL\Registration\\sharepoint.ps1 ' "
```

This `sharepoint.ps1` is in charge for "enabling" SharePoint cmdlets in regular PowerShell. Here is the content of `sharepoint.ps1`

```
$ver = $host | select version
if ($ver.Version.Major -gt 1)  {$Host.Runspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"}
Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
Set-location $home
```